# What can I do to have this question reopened?

Tags: discussion

[One of my past questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/86452/how-can-i-develop-the-intuition-of-a-team-member) has been closed by the community as been "What to do" type of question, and hence off topic.

I work as an IT auditor in Information Security profession. I have been seeing improvements in more junior team members assertiveness and communication ability such as been more willing to defend one's work when challenged. However, one area junior team members still seem to be having trouble with **is building one's "sixth sense" and following one's gut feelings** when clear evidence might not be available, be incomplete, or is conflicting.

Just today, I checked some work done by junior members of the team, and noticed one area in the work papers that should have prompted more investigation. This was not done. In a lot of cases, its about pattern matching, spotting anomalies in data from different areas, and asking "what is missing?"

**How can I edit my original question so it can made on topic and re-opened?**

Comment: Its not a what do a do question, it is a how do I (or your team in this case) learn a skill.  Its not really about navigating the workplace so much as just doing the job... which is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

As your question state, you're asking us how to develop the skills of your team members, in a very specialized domain.

I don't think a question like this could be on-topic here as The Workplace address general questions here.

I invite you to visit https://security.stackexchange.com/.

Check their [help-center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question would be on topic. If you're not sure, ask in their meta site.

Otherwise, you can use their chat if your question doesn't fit on the site.

Comment: I can confirm - Security chat would be an excellent first stop. The question as it stands would be off topic on our site currently, for the reasons Walmart mentioned, but we can definitely help.